# D2L API: Creating a new section

Tags: c#, json, desire2learn

I am working on building an app that accepts orgunitid and creates a new section associated with orgunitid. I'm using c#.

Here is my code.

```
string orgUnitId = textBoxOrgUnitId.Text;
string sectionCreateRoute = "/d2l/api/lp/1.0/" + orgUnitId + "/sections/";
var client = new RestClient(host);
var valenceAuthenticator = new D2L.Extensibility.AuthSdk.Restsharp.ValenceAuthenticator(userContext);
var requestCreateSection = new RestRequest(sectionCreateRoute, Method.POST);
valenceAuthenticator.Authenticate(client, requestCreateSection);
```

And, the JSON data I should provide will look like this.

```
{
"Name": "Test Section",
"Code": "" ,
"Description": { "Content": "Test", "Type" : "HTML"  }
}
```

How can I create a new section with this JSON data.

Thanks,

Phillip

---

I've tried this code, but it still does not create a section.

```
string orgUnitId = textBoxOrgUnitId.Text;
string sectionCreateRoute = "/d2l/api/lp/1.0/" + orgUnitId + "/sections/";
var client = new RestClient(host);
var valenceAuthenticator = new D2L.Extensibility.AuthSdk.Restsharp.ValenceAuthenticator(userContext);
var requestCreateSection = new RestRequest(sectionCreateRoute, Method.POST);
requestCreateSection.AddJsonBody(new
{
    Name = "Section Test",
    Code = "156156",
    Description = new { Content = "Test", Type = "Html" }
});
valenceAuthenticator.Authenticate(client, requestCreateSection);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using ResSharp I would recommend calling the following method;

```
    public IRestRequest AddJsonBody(object obj)
    {
        this.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        return this.AddBody(obj, "");
    }
```

However in order to use this you need a C# object to represent that data. The class definitions would look something like this;

```
public class NewSectionPostBody
{
     public string Name;
     public string Code;
     public SectionContentType Description;
}

public class SectionContentType
{
     public string Content;
     public string Type;
}
```

With these and your existing code I can do the following;

```
var requestCreateSection = new RestRequest(sectionCreateRoute, Method.POST);
// use object initializer to make instance for body inline
requestCreateSection.AddJsonBody(new NewSectionPostBody{
      Name="Test Section",
      Code=String.Empty,
      Description= new SectionContentType { Content="Test", Type="HTLM" }

});
valenceAuthenticator.Authenticate(client, requestCreateSection);
```

RestSharp handles the object to json string serialization so you can basically just pass any object into that method and the resulting json will be used as the post body.

One last thing; if this is a one off request you don't even need to define the types I used for the body. You can just use the same inline initilization constructs to make an anonymous type if you were to just remove the classnames ie;

```
requestCreateSection.AddJsonBody(new {
          Name="Test Section",
          Code=String.Empty,
          Description= new { Content="Test", Type="HTLM" }

    });
```

^^ Rather than instantiating user defined class types I use anonymous types. If you're not able to reuse the types which make up the post body, this is a more efficient way of setting up the request.

Comment: In the AddJsonBody method, the definition for RequestFormat and AddBody don't exist...

Comment: Thanks for the help but I get an error still. 'System.Xml.XmlException' (Name cannot begin with the '<' character, hexadecimal value 0x3C) occurs in addjsonbody line.

Comment: @PhillipHG you're not supposed to be defining the AddJsonBody method, that is part of the `RestRequest` class in RestSharp, I took it from GitHub (the project is open source). I only expect you to use the code where I call `AddJsonBody` on `requestCreateSection`.

Comment: No definition for AddJsonBody not found.. error occurs

Comment: @PhillipHG you've got some problem with your references, a different version of RestSharp (get latest via nuget to ensure that's not the case), or you have not correctly copied the example. As you can see by looking a the code the method exists and I'm using it correctly in my example; https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/RestRequest.cs#L237 I recommend looking through the intellisense options and making sure you see at least some of those `RestRequest` methods, if they're not coming as options that should be a red flag that you're missing an import.

Comment: Thanks @evanmcdonnal. I've got the latest Authsdk and addjsonbody works but the problem is it does not create a section even if it run fine. I'll add my new code. Please read through it

Comment: @PhillipHG I'm not familiar with the auth library you're using so I can't comment on that. Could you possibly update the question with your raw request and response? If you don't know how to view these things there are a couple of options. One is to download and install a util like fiddler and have it running while you run the program, another is to add some logging or console IO to print the data while the program runs. If you're sending the request successfully D2L's response will give you a hint about what needs to be changed.

Comment: when I debug this program, the number of attempts for requestCreateSection is 0 while the number of attempts for other programs, which run fine are 1 or 2. And, RequestFormat is Json. Other than these, everything's same.